# Lack of output when converting to HTML 5 canvas in Flash CC

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, html5-canvas, flash-cc

so I've been using Flash to create an interactive graphic, even though most of the world now advises against flash. I'd done some previous experiments converting to HTML5 and seemed to work OK.

I soon realised that actionscript on the main timeline gets commented out so managed to port all my actionscript to a class and have my movieclips load from the library.

My project isn't complete but I got most of the functionality working and gave it a test. Nothing happened. I can see a lot of JS code and HTML but my movieclips are never loaded to the stage. Have I wasted a week of work?

What does HTML5 canvas accept? I didn't think my code was overly complicated

Here is my class anyway... (My .fla is just a few empty frames )

```
package {
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;



public class App extends MovieClip {

    var debtcapital:Number;
    var mergers:Number;
    var equity:Number;
    var syndicated:Number;
    var globally:Number;


    var piesize:Number; 

    var wedge1:Number;
    var wedge2:Number;
    var wedge3:Number;
    var wedge4:Number;








    function App() {
        stop();

        var button:rightBtn = new rightBtn;

        this.addChild(button);
        button.x=390;
        button.y=90;

        var button2:leftBtn = new leftBtn;

        this.addChild(button2);
        button2.x=90;
        button2.y=90;



        button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPrevSlide);

    function onClickPrevSlide(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(currentFrame-1);
    }

    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickNextSlide);

    function onClickNextSlide(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(currentFrame+1);
    }

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makePie);

    }

    public function makePie(e:Event):void {

        function valueToPercent($value:Number, $min:Number, $max:Number):Number {
        var myPercent:Number;
        var difference:Number = $max - $min;
        myPercent = (($value - $min) / difference)*360;

        return myPercent;
    }

    if(currentFrame == 1){
            debtcapital = 4131;
            mergers = 7620;
            equity = 6882;
            syndicated = 2728;
            globally = 21362;
        }

        if(currentFrame == 2){
            debtcapital = 6863;
            mergers = 11185;
            equity = 9925;
            syndicated = 3469;
            globally = 31442;
        }

        if(currentFrame == 3){
            debtcapital = 9739;
            mergers = 13344;
            equity = 10884;
            syndicated = 4930;
            globally = 38897;
        }

        if(currentFrame == 4){
            debtcapital = 6131;
            mergers = 4620;
            equity = 1882;
            syndicated = 7728;
            globally = 20362;
        }

    var firstwedge:Number = Math.round(valueToPercent(debtcapital, 0, globally));
    var secondwedge:Number = Math.round(valueToPercent(mergers, 0, globally));
    var thirdwedge:Number = Math.round(valueToPercent(equity, 0, globally));
    var fourthwedge:Number = Math.round(valueToPercent(syndicated, 0, globally));

    wedge1 = firstwedge;
    wedge2 = secondwedge;
    wedge3 = thirdwedge;
    wedge4 = fourthwedge;

        piesize = globally / 400;


        var wedge1start = -90
        var wedge1end = wedge1start + wedge1
        var wedge2end = wedge1end + wedge2
        var wedge3end = wedge2end + wedge3
        var wedge4end = wedge3end + wedge4



        var drawings:Sprite = new Sprite();         

        var coin:Coin = new Coin;



        this.graphics.clear();
        drawings.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFFFFFF);
        drawings.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.2);
        this.drawSegment(drawings, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge1start, wedge1end, 0x000000);
        this.drawSegment(drawings, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge1end, wedge2end);
        this.drawSegment(drawings, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge2end, wedge3end);
        this.drawSegment(drawings, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge3end, wedge4end);
        this.addChild(drawings);

        drawings.graphics.endFill();

        this.addChild(coin);
        coin.x=stage.stageWidth/2;
        coin.y=stage.stageHeight/2;

        coin.scaleX = piesize / 140;
        coin.scaleY = piesize / 140;
        this.addChild(coin);


        this.swapChildren(drawings, coin); // swaps two objects




    }



    public function drawSegment(target:Sprite, x:Number, y:Number, r:Number, aStart:Number, aEnd:Number, color:uint=0x0, step:Number = 1):void {
            // More efficient to work in radians
            var degreesPerRadian:Number = Math.PI / 180;
            aStart *= degreesPerRadian;
            aEnd *= degreesPerRadian;
            step *= degreesPerRadian;

            // Draw the segment
            target.graphics.moveTo(x, y);
            for (var theta:Number = aStart; theta < aEnd; theta += Math.min(step, aEnd - theta)) {
                target.graphics.lineTo(x + r * Math.cos(theta), y + r * Math.sin(theta));
            }
            target.graphics.lineTo(x + r * Math.cos(aEnd), y + r * Math.sin(aEnd));
            target.graphics.lineTo(x, y);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for any advice!!

Comment: How do you load the Flash content in the page? What's the role of the HTML5 Canvas with Flash?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear I've converted the project to HTML5 canvas after coding with actionscript. It has created all the necessary files and code, seemingly, but doesnt produce anything on testing

Answer (score 2):

They can't convert AS3 to HTML5 because AS3 is full programming and javascript/css/html5 aren't.  You can convert AS3 to a phone app because phone apps run off programming.  HTML isn't programming so it doesn't work - as3 does too much.

Adobe Edge products are for non-flash applications.  I think Adobe Edge Animate will produce HTML5 animations - javascript/css.  I'm not a user and I know some of the Edge products are in beta.

Comment: Flash Pro CC now allows publishing to HTML5 Canvas as well, just that you have to script in JS instead of AS3.
Edge Animate on the other hand, works with HTML pages and allows you to add CSS based animations to DOM elements.

Comment: Yes, you're right but I don't say that because people just see you saying "publish to HTML5."  I know you added Canvas and said no javascript but people don't get it or don't pay attention.

Answer (score 2):

Flash CC now supports publishing to HTML5 Canvas directly from the IDE (using the CreateJS libraries internally). However, it would require JS and CreateJS API scripting to add any kind of interactivity to your project.

When you copy-paste or convert any existing Flash and AS3 based project to HTML5 Canvas doctype, the AS3 code gets commented out because it is not supported. You need to re-write your scripts using Javascript and CreateJS APIs.

Flash CC can publish your graphic assets and animations etc. directly to HTML5 Canvas but it does not do automatic script conversions yet.

PS: There are minor differences in the two scripting languages but most of the commonly used APIs remain the same.